# How to prove that the series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left( {F_{n+1}} \right) ^{- {F_n}} \approx 1.619141630$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, fibonacci-numbers

Suppose that $F_n$ is the $n$th term of Fibonacci numbers. By numerical calculation I see that 
$$
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(  {F_{n+1}} \right) ^{- {F_n}} 
\approx 1.619141630
$$
The rate of convergence of the above series is too high. I mean, if we compute with 50 digits, for $n\geq 8$ the values of series is constant and is as follows 
$$
\sum _{n=1}^{n\geq8} \left(  {F_{n+1}} \right) ^{- {F_n}} 
\approx 1.6191416299151308574250170831329152667545274408795
$$
Now my question: How to proof that the above series is converge to $1.619141630$.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: These terms are going to zero very fast, all you need to do is show they are eventually bounded by a convergent geometric series.

Comment: Is the different indexing in the two displayed formulas (first base F_{n+1}, then F_n) intentional?

Comment: @TMM Is it possible to explain more your question. I can not figure out it. Thanks

Comment: First you wrote $(F_{n+1})^{-F_n}$ and then $(F_n)^{-F_n}$. Was that intentional, or is it a typo?

Comment: @TMM Oh excuse me, I wrote it wrong. I edit it. Thanks

Comment: Is there a general formula for $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (A^{B^n})$$ ?

Comment: The Fibonacci numbers have a closed form, without recursion, derived here: {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression}

And the sum you are getting looks an awful lot like the Golden Ratio--see the link I cited.:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is easy to prove that $F_n>n$ for $n>5$.

Hence, $\left(F_{n+1}\right)^{-F_n}<n^{-n}<e^{-n}$ for $n>5$.

Let $$x=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(F_{n+1}\right)^{-F_n}.$$

Then, for $k$ an integer greater than $5$, $$x - \sum_{n=1}^{k} \left(F_{n+1}\right)^{-F_n} = \sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty} \left(F_{n+1}\right)^{-F_n} < \sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty} e^{-n} = \frac{e^{-k}}{e-1}$$

Choosing $k=23$, we can conclude that 
$$ 1.619141629915 < x < 1.619141629974$$
and so, with all digits correct, $x$ is approximately 1.6191416299.

You can certainly get more precision by using something smaller than $e^{-n}$ (as $n^{-n}$ is *much* smaller than that, but it's nice to have an easy tail).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the number $1.619141630$ has a closed form like the golden number ($\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$).

Comment: Why do you think that? Plugging this value into the inverse symbolic calculator (http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html) yields nothing.

Comment: In case anyone is curious, the continued fraction begins [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 23, 1, 2, 1, 5, 7, 3, 2, 1, 3, 6, 15, 2, 1, 5, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 14, 212, ...].

Comment: Just it was a guess. Is it true that we conclude your method is correct not only for Fibonacci numbers but also for any increasing sequence number? Thanks

Comment: Yes, this method (i.e., bounding the tail of a series to get approximations of the sum) applies to many, many sums (and integrals).

Comment: Based on the last comment can we prove with this method the following relation $$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left( \sqrt {k} \right) ^{-\sqrt {k}} 
\approx 2.7883025704080670082$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59835/discussion-between-matthew-conroy-and-amin235).